# passing data to mailgun webhooks in laravel

Tags: email, laravel, mailgun

Im using laravel and configured mailgun to send mails

I want to use webhooks to track them.
so I need to send data with the message so I can track it using the web hook

for example attach a message id to each mail I send

tried to follow the mailgun documnation but no luck

this is my code for sending the mail

```
        $data = array('course_name' => $course_name,'grade' => $grade,'email' => $stud->email,
                "v:messageId" => "123");
            Mail::send('emails.stud_feedback',$data, function ($message) {
                    $message->to($this->email)->subject( $this->course);
                    $message->attach($this->file, ['as' => 'feedback']);
            });
```

according to the documnation the web hook should post me the message id,
but Im not getting it.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved by setting headers to the mail:

```
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', "{'messageid:123}'}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
Mail::send('emails.test',[]), function ($message) use ($subject, $from, $emails) {
    dd($message->getSwiftMessage()->getId());
});
```